# Extracting first two words of a string in Javascript using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to get the first two words of a string in JavaScript using regular expressions.

I am using:

```
var str = "Reed Hastings, CEO Netflix"; 
var res = str.match(/^\s*(\w+ \w+)/);
```

Which spits back - `Reed Hastings,Reed Hastings`

It's kind of working, but can anyone tell me why it is getting duplicated?

Comment: Can your words be separated with punctuation? If they are separated with spaces, use Marin's solution, no regex is required.

Comment: Sometimes there is a comma after the second word other times there is just a space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...why it is duplicated?

`match` returns an array where the first entry is the *overall* match for the entire expression, followed entries for the contents of each capture group you've defined in the regex. Since you've defined a capture group, your array has two entries. The first entry would have leading whitespace if anything matched the `\s*` at the beginning; the second wouldn't, beause it only has what's in the group.

Here's a simple example:

```js
var rex = /This is a test of (.*)$/;
var str = "This is a test of something really cool";
var match = str.match(rex);
match.forEach(function(entry, index) {
  snippet.log(index + ": '" + entry + "'");
});
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

> Sometimes there is a comma after the second word other times there is just a space

Your expression won't match that, it's only allowing for a space (and it's only allowing for *one* of them). If you want to allow a comma as well, and perhaps any number of spaces, then:

```
/^\s*(\w+[,\s]+\w+)/
```

Or if you only want to allow one comma, possibly with whitespace on either side

```
/^\s*(\w+\s*,?\s*+\w+)/
```

You might also consider two capture groups (one for each word):

```
/^\s*(\w+)\s*,?\s*+(\w+)/
```

**Example:**

```js
var str = "Reed Hastings, CEO Netflix"; 
var res = str.match(/^\s*(\w+)\s*,?\s*(\w+)/);
if (res) {
  snippet.log("Word 1: '" + res[1] + "'");
  snippet.log("Word 2: '" + res[2] + "'");
} else {
  snippet.log("String didn't match");
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "How are you doing today?";
var wordsArray = str.split(" ");
var result = wordsArray[0] + " " + wordsArray[1];
```

result will be "How are".

Comment: Obviously add a bit of error handling in, but I'd go with this over regex.

Comment: Depends on the actual data. If the white space can be tabs or if there can be multiple spaces, a regex would be more appropriate.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, however.

Answer (score 0):

A regex solution to grab only words from the beginning of a line (even split by punctuation):

```js
var re = /^([a-z]+)[\s,;:]+([a-z]+)/i; 
var str = 'Reed Hastings, CEO Netflix';
var m;
 
if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = m[1] + " " + m[2];
}
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```

[T.J.Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29890339/3832970) gave you an explanation why you have 2 entries after `match`, the main point is that there is always a 0th group in a regex object that is equal to the full match. `N(stringsInArray) = N(capturing groups) + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

remove the ^ in front and make the expression global. ^ means beginning of a string so it will only matches for Reed Hastings.

```
str.match(/\s*(\w+ \w+)/g)
```